# Metal Lattice & Aircraft

Tags: aircraft

So I have been doing some reading up on emerging technologies in the aerospace industry and I stumbled upon something interesting.  Apparently, some researchers have developed an extremely light yet very strong metal that can withstand all sorts of impacts and is even flexible.  Supposedly, the metal can be bent like lead, but unlike lead it goes back to it's normal shape on its own.

So my question is....Are these viable options for rigid airships or even hybrid aircraft?  It seems to me that one of the major things keeping airships grounded is the cost of upkeep - wind tears little holes all over the ship.  However, airships obviously provide a huge benefit over airplanes - they can stop in the air without falling out of the sky.  Lift is obviously pointless once you get into space but it's a different story here on Earth.  I still think gasses like helium, hydrogen and even hot air provide a much more desirable lift force than say the wings on an airplane or even the force from a rocket.

Perhaps these light materials can make smaller and more robust aircraft for the coming years?  It's all so very interesting.  Thanks to anybody with a response.

Comment: in case it's not clear from the title, the material in question is metal lattice

Comment: could you give me a link to where you read this? I don't seem to figure out what metal lattice is. From google all I'm getting is metal bonding

Comment: Excuse me, the proper name would be Metallic microlattice, wikipedia has some stuff up about it.  I know airlines have devoted some research to this but I do believe their intents are for use with conventional airplanes.  The microlattice (rather than lattice) is 99.9% air which is quite interesting.  Seems almost like a metallic sponge.

Comment: "**I still think gasses like helium, hydrogen and even hot air provide a much more desirable lift force than say the wings on an airplane**" I  partly disagree. You can read those questions:http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15828/lighter-than-air-aircraft And http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9860/why-are-airships-not-more-popular

Comment: I think this is engineering rather than physics. It might be worth asking on the [Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: We've been building airplanes for over 100 years, and we've gone from manned gliders to SSTs, so we pretty much know what we're doing. Yes, strength is important, and so is weight, whether the aircraft is heavier or lighter than air. What's more, all metals have an *elastic limit*, which is the maximum stress they can handle and still return to their original shape. That's how springs work. More stress than that, and they bend or break. If we're talking about something new here, it's a little more subtle than that.